# Error 503 when running gwt:run

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I am trying to run a GWT app with Maven using this command:

```
$mvn gwt:run
```

However when accessing `http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html`

Browser throws HTTP Error 503.

Here's the complete POM, what could be wrong here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.mygwtapp.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.mygwtapp.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>mygwtapp::App</name>

  <properties>
    <errai.version>4.0.0.Beta1</errai.version>
    <gwt.version>2.8.0-beta1</gwt.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.5.11</slf4j.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <javaee.version>1.0.2.Final</javaee.version>
    <webappDirectory>src/main/webapp</webappDirectory>
  </properties>

  <!-- These must be here in this order because of missing guava-gwt snapshots in the JBoss Public Repository. -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Repo</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-public</id>
      <name>Sonatype Public Snapshots Repo</name>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/public</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.errai.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>errai-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${errai.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
        <version>20.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
      <artifactId>errai-javaee-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
      <artifactId>errai-cordova</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-elemental</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtquery</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwtquery</artifactId>
      <version>1.5-beta1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
      <version>${javaee.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
      <artifactId>errai-cdi-jboss</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
      <artifactId>errai-cdi-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mygwtapp.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>services</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.4.0,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <skip />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[2.1,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gwt.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
          <noServer>false</noServer>
          <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx2048m -XX:CompileThreshold=7000</extraJvmArgs>
          <disableCastChecking>true</disableCastChecking>
          <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
          <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
          <optimizationLevel>0</optimizationLevel>
          <style>PRETTY</style>
          <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
          <strict>true</strict>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>${basedir}</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>src/main/webapp/app/</include>
                <include>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deploy/</include>
                <include>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/</include>
                <include>**/gwt-unitCache/**</include>
                <include>.errai/</include>
              </includes>
            </fileset>
          </filesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exploded</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Surely rather than guess, you could find the specific stack trace output after running this maven command and hitting the URL that gives the 503 response right? I'd bet that'll give everyone a lot more to go on as far as what you still need to do to setup a full gwt app. EG you'll need a host page and the classes you list in the pom need to be built and packaged into the war too.

Comment: Verify your war source contents are getting copied to the war output directory (exploded war directory) before running dev mode.

Comment: @Branflake2267 I can see that the webapp files are not copied in the `gwt/devmode/war` folder however what can be done to make sure `gwt:devmode` copies it?